# Add Custom Attribute to Admin User: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom

I want to add an extra attribute to the admin user form. I searched but unable to find anything guide me plz.[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Ghulam.M. works perfectly, but it doesn't show the correct value once you saved, due to the empty value on addValues. I improved the answer with showing the correct values.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Tab;
class Main
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Registry  */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry)
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * Get form HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundGetFormHtml(
        \Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        /** @var $model \Magento\User\Model\User */
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('permissions_user');

        $form = $subject->getForm();
        if (is_object($form)) {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('cus_fieldsetname_code', ['legend' => __('Authorization Code')]);
            $fieldset->addField(
                'custom_column',
                'text',
                [
                    'name' => 'custom_column',
                    'label' => __('Custom Column'),
                    'id' => 'custom_column',
                    'title' => __('custom_column'),
                    'required' => false,
                    'note' => 'Custom column '
                ]
            );
            $form->addValues(
                [
                    'custom_column' => $model->getData('custom_column'),
                ]
            );
            $subject->setForm($form);
        }
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done somewhat similar to this for this first you have to upgrade the `admin_user` table using `UpgradeSchema`

> UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;
     use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
     class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
    {
        public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $setup->startSetup();
             //handle all possible upgrade versions
             $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();
            $connection = $installer->getConnection();
             if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
                //code to upgrade to 1.0.1
                if ($connection->tableColumnExists('admin_user', 'custom_column') === false) {
                    $connection
                        ->addColumn(
                            $setup->getTable('admin_user'),
                            'custom_column',
                            [
                                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                'length' => 256,
                                'nullable' => true,
                                'comment' => 'custom_column'
                            ]
                        );
                }
             }
             $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

> adminhtml/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main">
        <plugin name="admin_user_field" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Tab\Main" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Main.php

```
    <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\User\Edit\Tab;
 class Main
{
    /**
     * Get form HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundGetFormHtml(
        \Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $form = $subject->getForm();
        if (is_object($form)) {
            $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('cus_fieldsetname_code', ['legend' => __('Authorization Code')]);
            $fieldset->addField(
                'custom_column',
                'text',
                [
                    'name' => 'custom_column',
                    'label' => __('Custom Column'),
                    'id' => 'custom_column',
                    'title' => __('custom_column'),
                    'required' => false,
                    'note' => 'Custom column '
                ]
            );
             $form->addValues(
                [
                    'custom_column' => '', 
                ]
            );
             $subject->setForm($form);
         }
         return $proceed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the answer of Ghulam.M work with M2.3 declartive schema you can replace the UpgradeSchema file with the new declarative schema file which would look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="admin_user">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="custom_column" padding="5" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="false"
        default="0" comment="custom_column"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```